# Set TimeOut directive for different locations in Apache

Tags: apache, location, timeout, virtualhost

Is it possible to set the [`TimeOut`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#timeout) directive for different locations in an Apache virtual host?

```
<Location "/fast">
  TimeOut 5
</Location>

<Location "/slow">
  TimeOut 180
</Location>
```

Answer (score 11):

No. The documentation you linked to has this:

> TimeOut Directive
>
> Context:  server config, virtual host

And the Context is [explained like this](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/directive-dict.html#Context):

> This indicates where in the server's configuration files the directive is legal. It's a comma-separated list of one or more of the following values:
>
> **server config**
>
> This means that the directive may be used in the server configuration files (e.g., httpd.conf), but not within any `<VirtualHost>` or `<Directory>` containers. It is not allowed in .htaccess files at all.
>
> **virtual host**
>
> This context means that the directive may appear inside  containers in the server configuration files.
>
> **directory**
>
> A directive marked as being valid in this context may be used inside `<Directory>`, `<Location>`, `<Files>`, `<If>`, and `<Proxy>` containers in the server configuration files, subject to the restrictions outlined in Configuration Sections.
>
> **.htaccess**
>
> If a directive is valid in this context, it means that it can appear inside per-directory .htaccess files. It may not be processed, though depending upon the overrides currently active.
>
> The directive is only allowed within the designated context; if you try to use it elsewhere, you'll get a configuration error that will either prevent the server from handling requests in that context correctly, or will keep the server from operating at all -- i.e., the server won't even start.

Having TimeOut in the wrong context causes the configtest action to fail and Apache won't start.

Comment: This is the kind of answer I expect in SO, not only does it answer the question, but it also gives the reasoning and how to find the context for any Apache directive. From the bottom of my heart: **thank you**. Shame we could only upvote an answer once, otherwise I would have spend my 40 daily vote on this answer.